# How do I debug with NSLog(@"Inside of the iPhone Simulator")?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nslog

I'm used to programming and having log messages be viewable. I know you used to be able to use `NSLog()` to trace out messages when debugging Cocoa applications. What is the best way to "trace" messages when coding in an iPhone Xcode development environment?

Comment: iCode4Humans gives a good tutorial on customizing NSLog (if it helps): http://icode4humans.com/nslog-some-examples/

Answer (score 215):

There's a far more convenient way to trace with log messages in Xcode, and that's using Breakpoint Actions.

On the line of code where you'd be tempted to add a printf or NSLog, set a breakpoint, then control-click it and choose "Edit Breakpoint".  In the blue bubble that appears, click the + button on the right to open the Breakpoint Actions:
 [alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Breakpoint%20Actions.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Breakpoint%20Actions.png)

Enter your log text there.  Any expression that can be printed in the Debugger can be used when delimited by @ signs.

For debugging Objective-C it's generally more useful to choose "Debugger Command" from the popup and enter 'po [[object method] method]' to print the description string of an Objective-C object or the result of a method call.

Make sure to click the "Continue" checkbox at the top right so execution continues after the log.

Advantages of this over NSLog and printf:

- It's on the fly.  You don't have to
  recompile and restart to add or edit
  log messages. This saves you a lot of
  time.
- You can selectively enable and
  disable them.  If you learn enough
  from one, but its spew is
  interfering, just uncheck its Enabled
  box.
- All the output is generated on your
  Mac, never on the iPhone, so you
  don't have to download and parse
  through logs after the fact.
- The chance of shipping console spew
  in your application is significantly
  decreased.

Also check out the Speak button; it's great for debugging full-screen apps where you can't see the debug log.

Comment: There's one more advantage which, in my opinion, is the best of all: When developing in a team (using SCM), I hate to have my console cluttered with debugging output of other developers. Using your method, debugging output is not committed to the source code or project and will only be seen on the local machine where it was created.

Comment: Love it.  @Nikolai, agreed, but there's also an appropriate place for normal logging.  This method should not exclude properly placed logging at points of critical failure.  You're right though, I think most devs over-log and create clutter.

Comment: I don't get how to use it.
Please give an example equivalent to NSLog(@"x %f",myView.center.x);

Comment: Is there a way to log without stopping at the breakpoint, as you would with NSLog?

Comment: One thing... if you have a block of code with an "if" statement... An nslog placed inside the "if" statment will only be called if the "if" statement is true. For some reason, the breakpoint method gets called regardless of whether the "if" statement is called.  This limits the usefulness for me because one of the best uses of an nslog is knowing if an "if" statement was called.

Comment: I like this idea and I think I'll use it from time to time. But I see a big disadvantage as well - It's too easy to wipe, and although there is a comment saying that seeing logging from other developers is a minus, I think exactly the opposite. There is a huge advantage to have built in logging that helps you trace program execution that stays with the code and is not wiped by removing all break points or giving the code to another developer. For this sort of logging, defines are your friend.

Comment: It's even more improved -- with some of the previous objections now covered -- in Xcode 4.3!  Breakpoints don't have to stop execution, they can be ignored until a number of times you specify, and others.  Give it a look!

Comment: Err, Xcode 4.2 -- I realized that after the 5 minute edit window closed here!

Comment: It's good in it's place but other disadvantages include: no code completion, far worse performance then NSLog for real-time NSStringFrom… functions on devices, ugly casting.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a great bit of code I picked up somewhere on the web. It defines new functions DLog() and ALog(). DLog messages only appear when the app is compiled with a -DDEBUG flag (define DEBUG). ALog messages ALWAYS appear (even in Release mode).

```
// DLog is almost a drop-in replacement for NSLog
// DLog();
// DLog(@"here");
// DLog(@"value: %d", x);
// Unfortunately this doesn't work DLog(aStringVariable); you have to do this instead DLog(@"%@", aStringVariable);
#ifdef DEBUG
#       define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#       define DLog(...)
#endif

// ALog always displays output regardless of the DEBUG setting
#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Comment: I've used this in the past and it worked well for me at the time...You just have to make sure you have "other C flags" defined for "-DDEBUG", "-DRELEASE", etc.

Comment: There's plenty of example code around using defines like this. The advantage to doing so is that with a simple preprocessor setting in your debug build you can have a whole trace of you code appear in the logs.

Answer (score 4):

In my project I have a customised solution based on [DebugOutput.m](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/filename-and-line-number-with-nslog-part-ii.html) This adds the file & line number to the debug output, making it easier to identify where that output text is coming from, while still keeping it brief.

I've augmented the standard solution with a debug mask, so that I can switch debugging on and off for particular areas of functionality in my app. In Debug.h, I have

```
typedef enum {
kDebugMaskAp- = 1,
kDebugMaskXMLParser = 1 << 1,
kDebugMaskNetwork = 1 << 2,
kDebugMaskAnalytics = 1 << 3,
kDebugMaskCache = 1 << 4,
} debugBitMask;

#define debugForComponent(mask,format,...) if( currentDebugMask() & mask) [[DebugOutput sharedDebug]  output:__FILE__ lineNumber:__LINE__ input:(format), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

And in Debug.m

```
-(void)output:(char*)fileName lineNumber:(int)lineNumber input:(NSString*)input, ...
{
  va_list argList;
  NSString *filePath, *formatStr;

  // Build the path string
  filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:fileName length:strlen(fileName) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  // Process arguments, resulting in a format string
  va_start(argList, input);
  formatStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:input arguments:argList];
  va_end(argList);

  // Call NSLog, prepending the filename and line number
  NSLog(@"File:%s Line:%d %@",[((DEBUG_SHOW_FULLPATH) ? filePath : [filePath lastPathComponent]) UTF8String], lineNumber, formatStr);

  [filePath release];
  [formatStr release];
}
```

In the application, calls look something like this:

```
debugForComponent(kDebugMaskApp,@"Request failed - error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this in your prefix header. ALL logs from project will dissappear for sure .

```c
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__

#    define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)

#else

#    define NSLog(...) {}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) which brings a lot more to the table than just logging your messages. I use macros to disable logs in release builds, while leaving every single one of them active in debug builds. The log volume is not an issue, as NSLogger offers powerful log filtering options.

Answer (score -2):

I simply use the replace all functionality....

I disable all my NSLog statements by replacing NSLog(@" with //***NSLog(@"

That way I can simply find it (using find in all project files) with //***NSLog(@" and re-enable them

Nothing fancy but it works :)

Comment: One minor tip for users looking for a Replace All button: There is no Replace All button in Find in Project window, that is because when none of the matches is selected, Replace button does a Replace All.

Comment: This is a tad dangerous when using Version Control...!

Comment: This is not really a good idea. It's too easy to forget or get wrong. And it depends on the developer getting it right every time, not to mention it's a manual task. The best option is to make use of defines as mentioned in another reply.

Comment: The real danger is if you're the sort to not use { braces } when they're optional.  Then if you comment out the NSLog() invocation (assuming you have a line break before it) you're left with something like "if ( foo ) // NSLog( @"blah" )" which will then make the next code block conditional.  (Even #defines can be a concern with this style of coding.)

Comment: Instead of this, I put my NSLogs in an if statement using constant #defined in .m file.  I can enable/disable logs for a specific .m file--and always check-in to version control with NSLogs disabled.