# Is there any way to create a log file on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to log my iPhone application activity in a log file on the device. Could you please let me know how can I do that? How can I access the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  see

[How do I debug with NSLog(@"Inside of the iPhone Simulator")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558568/how-do-i-debug-with-nsloginside-of-the-iphone-simulator)

which reviews a number of approaches of getting log information from the simulator or from the iphone (tethered) while using the development environment.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I am doing now, viewing  the NSLog output/printf in XCode. However, I wanted the log info to be saved as a text file on the device.

Comment: If what you want is a way to get logs back from your developer hardware after using it untethered, or from non developer users, that's a different question you could ask.

Do you expect these logs to show normal or abnormal behaviour?

Comment: I have done this in the past, looking for evidence of it now in my git logs.

Comment: You might find this page interesting.

http://recapturing.blogspot.com/2009/05/getting-paths-to-directories-of-iphone.html