# How to remove the session start code from XCode 3.2

Tags: xcode, macos

I recently updated to the new version of XCode and the session start code is very long and appears every time I run the program. Is there any way to shorten it to what it was like in previous versions? (Just the first line)

Here's what it says now...

```
[Session started at 2009-09-14 18:49:17 -0400.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1344) (Fri Jul  3 01:19:56 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 1599]
Running…
```

Comment: The gdb executable is located in Developer/usr/bin/gdb...Is there any way to edit this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is unavoidable console output. That being said it is possible to clear the console once that output has been printed to give you "clean" application output thereafter. Note that there are several places where gdb communicates with you through the console (e.g., [breakpoint actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558568/how-do-i-debug-with-nsloginside-of-the-iphone-simulator)) so silencing it entirely is not something you'd want to do.

Comment: is there any reason they have added the extra output? I believe that it only printed the first line before this update.

Comment: My guess is that they updated gdb and it's update includes this new, more verbose output.

Comment: So I found this http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gdb.1.html, which says I can enter "quiet" to silence the intro message. I opened gdb in terminal and tried to enter it and it said it was an unrecognized command. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: My reading of those docs is such that it's not a command `gdb` accepts, but rather a parameter that has to be passed to `gdb` on startup, which is handled within XCode itself. I don't know of a way to get access to the parameter set being passed to `gdb`.