# What's the shortcut for the context info?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know the word for that. But there was a keyboard shortcut when you had the cursor on a method or variable, it showed an info box with all available variables/methods for that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

By the way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago) has a lot of other Xcode tips you may find useful.

Comment: Who voted this down?  Pressing esc will give you a list of completions for what you're currently typing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP is talking about the Research Assistant, which you can choose from the Help menu or invoke with Control-Command-? (Control-Command-Shift-/)