# Isn't there a Go To Last Edit Location shortcut in XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide, editor, intellij-idea

I'm rather new to `XCode` and I still miss so many shortcuts and features available in `IntelliJ IDEA`.

Perhaps the biggest pain point for me is the lack of a keyboard shortcut (or even a menu action) that allows you to *move through your most recent **change points*** (points in which you modified files).

In case you're familiar with `IntelliJ`, I'm referring to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut... (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> on a Mac)

I'm **NOT** referring to navigation through your recent view points (via <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>) - only locations you edited.

You can find some useful `XCode` tricks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago).

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem, undo+redo is only good if you are in the same file

Comment: I'm afraid not. But JetBrains' AppCode includes this functionality :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

⌘-Z then redo

Comment: I always use that, not just in XCode. ( that missing symbol is the command-key, for the folks unfortunate enough not to be on a mac. )

Comment: Thanks Kris.

I use "⌘-Z" and "Shift-⌘-Z" (redo) too, but it doesn't work if you move to another file, which is the main issue I think...

Furthermore, I sometimes want to iterate through all recent edit points and I can't do that with undo/redo because of the side effect of losing the changes :(

Answer (score 5):

I got here via Google. In Xcode 4 & 5 the shortcuts are

CTRL + Command + Back Arrow

CTRL + Command + Forward Arrow

Comment: it takes to last file  not to the last cursor location

Comment: This was relevant for XCode 4 & 5

Comment: This is for navigating back and forth, not for going directly to last edit location

Answer (score 2):

It's not available the way Jetbrains and other do it. Using AppCode might be a choice.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll through your recent changes in Xcode:

Push and hold Control + Command keys (holding them both down)
Then press and release the back arrow (in the bottom right of the Apple keyboard)
While still holding the Control and Command keys down, press the back arrow down again.

This will scroll through the changes you have made to the files in your project. I believe this will only show you the changes since the project was opened.