# xcode 4.2 and tabs not updating with file name; ruby code

Tags: ruby, xcode, xcode4.2

I use Xcode 4.2 for editing a rails app. If I open a file a ruby file in a tab, the tab name stays the same even if I open another file via Project Navigator or `Open Quickly`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make this update to the file name? Is anyone else having same problem?

Comment: "Is anyone else having same problem?" ... pretty sure most people don't use an IDE primarily designed for writing Objective-C, C++ and C applications to write ruby :P

Comment: hence the question and ruby specified in title; honestly kinda testing out xcode for this and seeing this as the biggest issue. There are other issues with tabs such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353220/how-can-i-make-the-tabs-work-normally-on-xcode-4

Comment: @timpone Check out my updated answer--I think it will solve your problem better than closing the tab and opening a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Most recent edit: **I have a solution to this.** Try double clicking on the filename to edit, select all, then delete and hit enter. It should change to the name of the current file and should start updating again.]

I have this same problem with Xcode 4.3.1 (4E1019), using Objective-C. Seems like an Apple bug.

[Edit: Just noticed you can rename tabs by double clicking the shown text--I'm wondering if I may have done this by accident when switching tabs. Perhaps without even changing the name, but Apple then sees that the tab name has been "customized" and so stops renaming it based on the file.]

[Edit: You can rename the tab by hand, which makes this slightly less annoying.]

Comment: Thank you! It was annoying having to close the tab, this saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

It also happens sometimes in my iOS project. I think it's an Xcode bug. When it happens, I just close that tab and use another tab.