# How can I enable vertical split views in the Xcode IDE?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm using Xcode on a multi-monitor setup.

Obviously I want to take advantage of the multiple monitors to view and edit multiple panes of source code, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to enable vertical split views.  In other IDEs, it's just an option you click in the "Window" menu.

How do I enable vertical split views in Xcode?

Comment: :)  actually, i would hope any person writing code is taking advantage of multiple monitors, considering how inexpensive it is to have these days.

Comment: Define "inexpensive"... It's very expensive for me. I certainly can't afford.

Comment: This also helpful :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago

Comment: With the 3-finger swipe gesture sliding quickly between screens on my mac I'm happy with one screen. :) I still look for ways to optimize my workflow, but one screen means my productivity doesn't suffer when I work away from home/office.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Xcode 4

Check out the options in the Navigate file menu item. I like Command+J. Also, while the Editor is active, i.e., you're editing code or your cursor is blinking in the Editor, press `Command+Option+,`. Or, you can Option-click (or Option+Shift-click) a file in the Navigator. Then, to make more room for editing, I like to press `Command+0` to hide the Navigator and, if they're not already hidden, `Command+Option+0` to hide the Utilities. Press Command+Enter to go back to the Standard Editor view.

#### Xcode 3

Hold down `alt` and click the little tiny box (with a horizontal line through it) in the upper-right-hand corner of the screen. It's underneath the tiny little lock icon.

Comment: Also, in the Editor, Ctrl-Click (right-click) for the context menu and select "Open in assistant editor"

Comment: Great tips. Note that, at least as of Xcode 5, you can opt to stack editors *horizontally* via `View > Assistant Editor > ...`.

Comment: "Hold down alt and click the little tiny box" still works in Xcode 15.

Answer (score 12):

**Xcode 9** for those coming from a search engine:

Click and hold on the Assistant Editor button for an options menu. Choosing "Assistant Editors on Right" will cause the view to be split vertically.

[image: Xcode Assistant Editor options]

Answer (score 5):

This has changed in Xcode 12, maybe earlier. All my `Option-Clicks` go to open second view appearing below rather than size by side. The solution is to go to `Views -> Change Editor Orientation`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

respect to  mattdipasquale

1. Command+J  --------Check out the options in the Navigate file menu item
2. Command+Option+,------editing code or your cursor is blinking in the Editor
3. Option-click (or Option+Shift-click)------open a file in the Navigator
4. Command+Enter----------reset

Answer (score 0):

Use the dropdown on the split icon to choose between different views

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 14 you just have to click this icon: [image]