# Is there a way to check how a macro "expands" in C or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

A macro is a preprocessor right. Sometimes we set things right sometimes we don't.

Wouldn't it be nice to once in a while expand the macro and see how it works?

Comment: A macro isn't a preprocessor - it's a source code construct which is processed by a program or part of a program known as a preprocessor. Also, what version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 preprocessor output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937031/xcode-4-preprocessor-output)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with most compilers, e.g. with gcc:

```
$ gcc -E
```

this just runs the preprocessor and then stops, giving you the pre-processed output on stdout.

If you're using Xcode though you don't even need to do this - depending on what version of Xcode you're using you can just select `Preprocess` from the `Build` menu (that's what its called in Xcode 3.x - if you're using Xcode 4 it may have been moved/renamed). See: [Xcode Preprocessor Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937031/xcode-4-preprocessor-output)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the XCode Preprocess function only works if your code builds properly. Which makes it next to useless for debugging macros that aren't compiling.

Comment: I just tried this with Xcode 7.2 and it seems that compile/link errors don't prevent you from generating preprocessor output - I expect it's only preprocessor errors which (not surprisingly) cause a problem ?

Comment: You're correct. It makes sense that there's a distinction, I was just bundling it all together into "build errors", which isn't specific enough. I was hoping to gain some insight into *why* my preprocessor define was messing up by looking at the preprocessor output, but because I had an error in it I wasn't able to see anything other than an error stating that the macro "could not be expanded".

Comment: Yes, I think when you have problems at the preprocessor level then you have to resort to something like a "divide and conquer' approach to isolate the problem.