# Macro for creating variables in C

Tags: c, macros

I want to create several variables of the form:

```
static char fooObjectKey;
static char bazObjectKey;
static char wthObjectKey;
static char myObjectObjectKey;
...
```

So I wrote

```
#define defineVar(x) static char #x ObjectKey

defineVar(foo);
defineVar(baz);
defineVar(wth);
defineVar(myObject);
```

but I get the error: `Expected identifier or }`

What am I doing wrong here? :)
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Most compilers can show you the result of the pre-processor. This is invaluable when trying to fully understand complex macros.

Comment: I am using LLVM in Xcode, Do you know how can I see the result? :)

Comment: @nacho4d with gcc is `gcc -E source.c` I think that with clang it's the same since clang offers a gcc-compatible driver so `clang -E source.c`.

Comment: Found how to do it in Xcode! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937031/xcode-4-preprocessor-output See @Steven Hepting's answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to concatenate them:

```
#define defineVar(x) static char x##ObjectKey
```

Explanation:

The preprocessor operator ## provides a way to concatenate actual arguments during macro expansion. If a parameter in the replacement text is adjacent to a ##, the parameter is replaced by the actual argument, the ## and surrounding white space are removed, and the result is re-scanned. For example, the macro paste concatenates its two arguments:

`#define paste(front, back) front ## back`

so `paste(name, 1)` creates the token `name1`.

Answer (score 3):

`#` in macro is used to stringify argument, `##` is used for concatenation in macro... in your case, following is the correct syntax..

```
#define defineVar(arg) static char arg##ObjectKey
```

if you use this,

```
#define defineVar(x) static char #x ObjectKey
```

variable declaration become...

```
static char "foo" ObjectKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double hash for concatenation

```
#define defineVar(x) static char x##ObjectKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The ## operator concatenates two tokens into one token
Hence 
defineVar(foo) will be replace with static char fooObjectKey
```