# How can I get @-directive-preprocessed Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c

How can I see a preprocessed Objective-C code in which the Objective-C directives like @property and @synthesize are preprocessed?

I've searched this topic in Stackoverflow, there's some tips for how to see preprocessed code, for example [Xcode Preprocessor Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937031/xcode-preprocessor-output). However, the "preprocessed code" does not involve preprocessed Objective-C directives. For example, in the "preprocessed code", the Objective-C directives like @property or @synthesize are not preprocessed.

Take the following code as an example,

```
    // ========= Person.h =========
@interface Person: NSObject
{
}
-(void) Print;
@property int age;
@end

// ========= Person.m =========
@implementation Person
-(void) Print
{
    NSLog(@"Print_Age:%d", _age);
}
@end
```

What I expect to see is something like this:

```
// ========= Person.h =========
@interface Person: NSObject
{
    int _age;
}
-(void) Print;
-(int) age;
-(void) setAge:(int) age;
@end

// ========= Person.m =========
@implementation Person
-(void) Print
{
    NSLog(@"Print_Age:%d", _age);
}
-(int) age {
    return _age;
}
-(void) setAge:(int) age {
    _age = age;
}
@end
```

How can I see it?

Comment: I don't get what your problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence contains the answer:

> @property or @synthesize are not preprocessed

These are part of the *language*, they have nothing to do with the preprocessor. You can no more see these constructs after preprocessing than you can a `while` loop.

If you wish to see what they are compiled to you can examine the assembler, Xcode menu item `Product > Perform Action > Assemble`.

HTH