# Keyboard command to select the details view in xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to minimize how much I use the mouse in xcode. Something that would really help me is the ability to navigate through files in the detail view with the keyboard. I know I can use the up/down arrows to navigate through them once one of the files in the detail view is selected, but I don't know how to select one of them without using the mouse. Can I switch focus to the detail view using only the keyboard?

Comment: I couldn't find that myself. Try this extensive list of tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top