# how to close a method/function on iPhone xCode?

Tags: iphone, function, methods, sdk

when your project is getting bigger and bigger we have to look for ways to make it more easy to read.

The point is, I want to close all my functions using any key short code in my Xcode, let see the picture attached to understand what I mean:

(I cannot set any picture becuase I need more reputation...)

Well I mean:

```
  > - (void) process1 {

  }
```

If we press on the row on top left, the process will get closed. How can I use a key short code to close all my functions/methods on my class (.m)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the *View→Code Folding* menu for options and hot-keys.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's here. You'll also find other cool stuff
[Hidden Features of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago)

Comment: Noam, really really useful information. I will print it out right now to keep it close to me onward. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I helped. You don't really need to comment, just vote up (left of the answer) and select your accepted answer.

Comment: I cannot vote up until I have 15 reputation... I will take as valid answer the first one, but I think your response is really adding value. As soon as I get 15 reputation I will come back and vote up you guys. Thank you!