# Hidden Features of Xcode 4

Tags: cocoa, ios, macos, xcode4, hidden-features

Now that Xcode 4 is officially released it's time for a follow up to my previous question: [Hidden Features of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode)

So what are they? What are those hidden little Xcode 4 hints & tips that you can't live without?

Please limit your tips to those that are *new and specific to Xcode 4!*

Answer (score 42):

If you like your code to look as good as it runs, you've undoubtedly used `#pragma mark -`  and `#pragma mark <name>` to provide a nice visual grouping in the Xcode class dropdown list. **Xcode 4 now combines these into a single `#pragma mark - <name>`**.

[More on pragma mark](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html).

[image: Xcode pragma mark]

Comment: Is the (slightly more portable) `// MARK: -` version working, too?

Comment: yes, both are fine: // MARK: - <name>    or    // MARK: <name> -

Answer (score 35):

- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd> click on a symbol lets you tell Xcode *exactly* where in the UI you want the navigated-to file to open.
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>ret</kbd> makes the version editor / assistant (the right hand pane) go away
- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to hide the debugger
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to hide the navigator (left pane)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>[1..n]</kbd> switch between navigators on left
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>[1..n]</kbd> switch between utilities (thing generally on right)
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[1..n]</kbd> switch between various related files in the editor

Overall, Xcode 4 tries to keep things consistent w/the hot keys.  Cmd is for mainline commands.  Adding modifiers is for analogous commands focused on one particular sub-feature.

(These are just the four that come to mind as the my most pounded upon shortcuts that I'm using constantly!  I'm sure it'll change over time as my workflow is refactored into the new hotness.)

Comment: Oooh... thanks for editing that, Dave.  Didn't know about <kbd>...</kbd>.

Comment: The ⇧⌘⌥-click thing is a fusion of two shortcuts: ⌘-click on any symbol to open the file that declares it, and ⇧⌥ to bring up the where-to-open-it pop-over. You can use the latter key-combo augmentation on a couple of other things, as I described in one of my answers.

Comment: Also, for those like me who used Interface Builder's ⌘-[1–6] shortcuts for the different Inspectors, those became the ⌘⌥-[1–7] you mentioned, when editing a nib.

Comment: Is there a way to use ⇧⌘⌥-click without actually using a mouse, but keyboard instead (and when caret is on a symbol you want to open)? ⌘⌥-, opens a new adjacent editor, but AFAICS only current file is considered.

Comment: ⇧⌘⌥-ret - show a visual diff of the current file.

I wanted to explicitly add this one since the new integrated diff viewer is one of my favorite improvements.  The time machine-like slider is a nice added touch.

Comment: Is there a way to hide all but the main editor window...? Essentially one command for Cmd + Return, Cmd + 0, Cmd + Shift + Y

Answer (score 18):

Xcode 4 adds a new "Code Snippets" feature, accessible via View > Utilities > Code Snippet Library. To add a new code snippet, select some text in the editor view and drag it into the snippet library. You can either drag a snippet out and drop it in your code to use it, or, much more conveniently, assign a completion shortcut to it.

When you type in that series of letters, it will automatically show up in the code completion pop-up menu as you type your code. For example, among many others, I have a snippet set up so that typing "svk" will expand to `setValue:<#value#> forKey:<#key#>`. This can save a lot of typing and/or fishing around in the autocompletion menu for the methods and other code expressions you use the most. Xcode ships with a bunch of built-in snippets that come in very handy as well.

Answer (score 15):

New shortcut I use most often: triple-finger swipe (up or down) to swap counterparts (between the interface and implementation files). No more hand acrobatics!

Thanks to https://twitter.com/xctotd/status/48148271759241216

Comment: @Dave DeLong, how can you do this on the keyboard? I was doing option-command-up to get from interface to implementation in XCode 3. This no longer works in 4. What's the new way?

Comment: @yar control-cmd-up/down arrow

Comment: Is this still the case in Lion? Cos in lion a 3 finger vertical swipe on the trackpad activates Mission Control. I'm assuming we're talking about trackpad swiping and not the magic mouse.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a simple solution currently, even if you switch Mission Control to a 4-finger swipe. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771057/trackpad-gesture-to-switch-to-header-source

Comment: @wdn It’s four fingers in Lion.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-click on a file in the <del>Groups and Files list</del> Project Navigator, or hold <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd> while choosing a file from the Jump Bar.

[You'll get a pop-over from which to pick where to open the file.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-general_preferences/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010441-CH1-SW2) New or existing tab, new or existing split (Assistant) editor, new window—every possible option is there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Very useful. It also works on the selected file in the 'Open Quickly' dialogue (⇧⌘O).

Comment: I love how so much work's gone into a little UI widget that most people will never see. :)

Answer (score 13):

Tabs in Xcode 4 are awesome. Each one maintains its own separate layout, so you can have multiple tabs with different things in them and have each one lain out appropriately.

I've been setting up my projects with [three layouts—one for the project object, one for each nib (showing the owner's class's sources), and one for each class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPWqB.jpg).

There is one bug here: As of 4.0, Xcode will reset the state (turning off any Assistants) of the active tab when you reopen the project. The workaround is to switch to a tab with no Assistants for Xcode to close before you close the project. I have filed this as Radar number 9178441.

Answer (score 10):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> pops down within-file segment of jump bar (enables keyboard-controlled jump to methods)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd>/<kbd>}</kbd> select previous / next tab
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> navigate to any editor (but why oh why doesn't TAB then cycle between them?)

Comment: Also, note that keyboard shortcuts are configurable. I changed previous/next tab to ⌘⌥⇠/⇢ to match Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

**Editor ShortCuts**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up/down</kbd> Jump between
  .h & .m Files.
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> Jump between Previous
  Edited Files/Next Edited files.

**Layout Shortcuts**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>            hide or show navigators
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>   hide or show inspectors
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> hide or show debugger console.

**Navigators Shortcuts**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>         Project
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>         Symbol
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>         Search
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>         Issue
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>     Debug
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> BreakPoint
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>         Log

**Tab Switching & Jumping**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>                 Previous Tab
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>                 Next Tab
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>                 Select location to jump
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>ClickFile</kbd>   Select location to open file
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> Select location to open Method

**Inspectors**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>    File Inspector
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>    Quick Help
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> Identity Inspector
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> Attribute Inspector
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>    Size inspector
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>    Connection Inspector

**Build Related**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>         Build
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>  Clean
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>             top

**Code Folding**

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> Minimize Current Method/Class/Interface
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>    Expand Current Method/Class/Interface
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> Minimize All Method/Class/Interface
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> Expand All Method/Class/Interface

Comment: these are not hidden features

Comment: @icnivad - many hidden features are accessible using shortcuts, like jumping files, tab switching etc.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the first. Tabs! Xcode 4 has replaced Xcode 3's useful but rarely used "favorites bar" with *persistent* tabs. This means you can keep a working set of commonly used documents in your tab bar.

Not exactly a hidden feature as such - but the fact that the tabs are persistent is perhaps easily missed.

Comment: Also, that you can assign custom names to the tabs, which was something I didn't know until Scott Stevenson mentioned it: https://twitter.com/scottstevenson/status/50270610038865921

Comment: Yep, You can double-click tabs in Xcode 4 to rename them, then use named tabs in Prefs > Behaviors (via @scottstevenson‎)

Comment: Oh, this is very handy. So I can set up a debugger/console tab showing only those, then have that show up during a run. This is much nicer than having it popping up and down all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Some useful hotkeys for working on smaller screens are:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> - Hide and show the console/debug area
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> - Hide and show the file navigation

Answer (score 6):

If you're having any sort of trouble with the indexing of your project (e.g. symbols not showing up in autocompletion), open the Organizer window, click the Projects tab, and use the "Delete" button to delete the derived data for your project. This will force a rebuild of the project's index, as well as tossing out any built products.

Answer (score 6):

You can now associate groups in the Project Navigator with folders on disk. It always bugged me before that the Xcode 3 file view may not represent the actual structure of the project on disk.

Create a new group, then with the new group highlighted, open the File Inspector. In the identity section on the right just below the 'Path' is a small icon, click this to open the file browser dialog allowing you to select the directory for this group.

[image: File Inspector]

Comment: What's new here? You could always link groups to directories (Xcode 3: Command-I on the group)

Answer (score 5):

If you hold the FN key then you can scan through your document with the cursorkeys, without moving the cursor

Answer (score 5):

### Jump bar:

if your write outside function:

```
// FIXME: A Bug
// TODO: Later
// ???: ???
// !!!: !!!
// MARK: This a mark
```

Will like:
[image]

Also you can search:
[image]

Click with <kbd>Option</kbd>(With <kbd>Shift</kbd> at the same time, you can choice another window), you can see a dialog letting you specify where the file should open:

[image]

### Source control:

If you use svn or git, discard change is easy:
[image]

### Interface buidler

In xcode 4.2, you can jump to interface builder here:

[image]

Click a ui object with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it will show a list of all objects under the point.

[image]

Try this:
Select a ui object, hold <kbd>Option</kbd>, then move mouse over other objects. It will like:

[image]

### Other

Hotkey: <kbd>Shift+Command+O</kbd> Open Quickly

Try:

```
#error message
#warning message
```

And read:
[Writing and Editing Source Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Editing/Editing.html)

Answer (score 4):

*Text Editor*:

- **Cmd-clicking** on a class name will take you to the implementation (or header) file of that class, cmd-clicking on an object will take you to where the object is declared.
- **Alt-clicking** will open a documenation popup for the object you clicked on.

*Adding frameworks*: You cannot simply do this by right-clicking on the project or a group (like in Xcode 3). You need to go to the project view, select your target and go to "Build Phases" tab. Frameworks can be managed under the "Link Binary with Libraries" section.

*Setting target dependencies*: Similar to the above, in the "Target Dependencies" section of the "Build Phases" tab.

*Keep your archives safe* -prior to installing Xcode 4 (from 3). You will lose them (most likely) and with them lose your ability to symbolicate your crash logs.

*Delete action-BEWARE*: "Delete" (instead of "Remove Reference Only") directly erases the file from your drive. It doesn't go into the Trash, so you cannot recover it.

Comment: DELETE is Horrible. I can't get it back from TRASH :(

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> jumps to the editor, but if you have more than one editor open you get an overlay that has all of the open editors.  you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> to switch between the open editors.

Also, if you are having a hard time finding an option or property for anything the utilites window is probably your best bet:

`hide and show utilities:` <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>

Things that are commonly hidden here that aren't intuitive:

- data model entity properties.
- data model properties
- xib properties

Answer (score 4):

- You ***don't need to declare IBAction*** - methods in .h File. & You can directly connect it in Interface Builder.

Example:

```
-(IBAction)btnLogInTapped:(id)sender {
    // place following method in .m file of your code. save file. Open the
    // .xib file of viewController
    // click on files owner
    // click on connection-inspector.
    // you can view your methods under "received actions"
}
```

- You **don't need to declare variables**, if you are creating property for it.

Example:

```
// a property declared in .h File of your view controller.
@property (nonatomic, retain) LogInVCtr *nxtLogInVCtr;

// synthesize above property in .m File
@synthesize nxtLogInVCtr;
// or
@synthesize nxtLogInVCtr = _nxtLogInVCtr;
// and you are done, you don't need to declare variable for it.
```

Answer (score 3):

One of my favorites is the "Open Tab" behavior preference. If you go to "Behaviors" in Preferences, you can set it to go to a specific tab whenever a run starts. You can name the tab, something like "Debug" and Xcode4 will create it for you if it doesn't exist, and take you there when you start debugging. You can configure this tab just how you like it for debugging sessions, and it will stick that way after you close it, so whenever you do a run Xcode4 will be set up just how you want it, in a separate tab. You can even tear this tab off to a separate window, in which case Xcode4 will open a new specially configured "Debug" window each time you start a run! This feature is great because it keeps your regular code editing tab or window uncluttered with the log and debugger panes. Simply close the "Debug" window when you're done running and you can be back to your clean screen of code.

Comment: Brilliant!  This has been bugging me for ages.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode3, There was an option for "Rename the Project". Now, you just need to click twice ( second click slowly ) to rename the project & Its done.

Answer (score 2):

**To Limit the Number of Concurrent Build Operations**

This is a (somewhat) hidden preference which allows you to define the number of concurrent compile tasks:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4
```

**To Disable Indexing in the IDE**

This one disables code sense indexing, which can save a lot of resources in large projects:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

to reenable:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable
```

Note that you should quit Xcode, set the preference values as desired, changes take effect when you restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using vim/emacs running on, say, Terminal, or any other external editor, you can just create your xcode project, add files and whatnot and then switch to editing said files using whichever edit suits you best; whenever you switch focus to an xcode4 window, the modified files will be reloaded( was also the case with Xcode3 ) and you can build / run your application.

Answer (score 1):

Two kinds of ***Build location specification*** using XCode4 Preferences.

1. Location Specified By **Targets** - 'Build' Directory is located within your project directory.
2. Location in **Derived Data** ( Recommended by XCode, as you can see in screen shot ) - 'Build' Directory is located under DerivedData location specified ( e.g. here in my case, `/Users/digicorp/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData` )

Please look at following screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**QUICK HELP**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Find the Quick help. For example,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strQuery;
```

My Text cursor is at `NSString` & if I press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>** then It will show a quick documentation in the inspector/utilities.