# How to quickly access documentation in Xcode 4.5.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4

How can I quickly access the documentation for a symbol, method, enum, etc. in Xcode 4.5?

alt + click on symbol shows a quick-info. Apple removed the dictionary icon which opened the documentation. I tried all other possible shortcuts of the cmd / alt / shift / click mumbo jumbo dance and none of them open the documentation browser.

I suppose there is a hidden trick to quickly open it anyways?

**Edit: Figured out this new quick-info box has a link to the documentation.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**⌘ Command + Double-Click** on a symbol: Jump to Definition of a symbol.

**⌥ Option + Double-Click** on a symbol: Find Text in Documentation of a symbol. (Only works if you have they symbol's Doc Set installed.)

You should check [This URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode) to know more about short cuts

Comment: Command + double click opens the definition in a new window. Command + single click jumps to definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Alt + double click** any symbol to open the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You said in your question "quickly", quite frankly xcode sucks when it comes to reading docs quickly

I suggest you install the free [Dash](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12) from the app store - which is a documentation viewer that is considerably quicker than xcode

Then install this plugin for Xcode

```
https://github.com/omz/Dash-Plugin-for-Xcode
```

Now doing "alt + click" on a symbol opens up Dash to the correct docs in a flash